# Rails - loading page Parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parallel-processing

The idea is to have a page with a parallel process and in the same time show a loading .gif or a JS game because the waiting is soo long, like this:

[image]

So, that's basically the idea, enter a controller that lauch a parallel process that's takes a lot of time meanwhile display his page that have something to 
entertain the user and, by ajax, is constantly checking if the parallel process is done, so display a button to continue to the next page

Consider that is done this way because the process itself takes over 10 minutes of time so the timeout of the server kills the process before it's complete so in this idea the timeout is completed when is display the wait.html.erb and in the same time the parallel process is still alive

Also consider that i don't do anything yet because i don't know if the very idea is possible, so my question is if its possible? and how will be done?

Comment: Have you looked at the ruby parallel gem? https://github.com/grosser/parallel

Comment: yes @trh, unfortunately what i need is that the parallel function runs in the background, after the controller function is done and shows the view; and the parallel gem waits until all the threads finish to show the view

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use background processing worker ([Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) in this example):

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(user_id)
    VeryLongProcess.run
    notify(user_id)
  end
end
```

And the `notify` method could either push notification to user (using Websockets for example) or just store a setting in Redis or other DB that the job has completed. This in turn could be read by your AJAX call.